# How do you test your your wireframes?

Tags: usability-testing, wireframe

Do you usually test with real users or with your internal team first?

Comment: "test them all"

Comment: sorry, UX.SE is not the place for surveys and polls, this question has no possible correct answer (or all are correct)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends a lot on what are you testing, what's your intended function, what stage of design are you in right now.

Usually, most designers go through some sort of understanding phase at the start of the project, continue with more concrete ideas and finish with evaluating their project empirically.

You can do usability testing and evaluation in any of these stages though (it is highly recommended).

Users you test with should have some aspects common with your target audience. 
 If your product is very broadly targeted though, feel free to get opinions from as many people you have time to, hallway tests are recommended. You just need to be careful about who is giving you feedback, e.g. developer might think about their app very differently than your grandma.

Answer (score 0):

**To me wireframes** are quick doodles in a whiteboard or a paper. I use wireframes to design and demonstrate the user's path and information structure. At this stage in design is always good to meet with the front end team and the back end and have a good brainstorm session. You can talk about all your ideas and initiatives. Is a process of discovery and understanding the user journey.

**Prototype**
When i prototype i usually use a online tool like invision and share all my prototypes for testing with customer support, Project managers and also i organize users session. On this user sessions i give the user a few exercise to complete to see the journey and see if they can complete task.

Every process is different depends your customer or company.

Answer (score 0):

Being as brief as possible:

> Do you usually test with real users or with your internal team first?

Internal team will be preferable since it doesn't cost you at all and it does help to find minor errors before going big and spending money with real users. Usually from 6-8 user tests will be good enough to find these errors. Just remember that they must not be familiar with the prototype.

> How do you test your your wireframes?

There are plenty of ways. Some of them are InVision, UXPin, Pixate, Balsamiq, UserTesting, Axure, Loopback, simple user tests, paper, and more. It basically depends on the level of fidelity of your mock-up **and your needs.** For that you and your team must ask and answer the following question: What do we want to measure?